# handling constant columns in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

How should I handle columns, in a binary classification context, that have the same value in all rows? What if I have multiple columns of this type?

Answer (score 6):

Constant features do not bring in any value to ML Model. They should not be used in ML Models. Even if you use them if you use regularization they will not be selected as important variables in the model

Comment: Thank you @Ashwiniku918 for answering! How to specify a variation threshold of a column so I can consider that column? In other words: if I have columns that have the same value for almost all rows except for some rows, when should I delete these columns as well?

Comment: Its depends on business use case. Threshold can vary a lot from problem to problem. I would suggest to use Regularization to tackle this problem. So that you don't need to remove them manually. Trees based algorithm will anyways not use this column

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Ashwiniku918!

Comment: If you have rare instances where the value in this feature is different, you should really understand why, and see if the different value correlates to the target. Say you want to predict a rare outcome (an individual will be convicted of pedophile) and the feature is “past pedophilia conviction”.

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing the example. This is exactly a example where low variation columns can also we very useful

Comment: thanks @famargar for the remark!

Answer (score 5):

These columns can be removed, they are completely useless for the ML algorithm. If they are kept, they will be ignored by the model.

The features are meant to be indicators which help determine the target. If a feature always contains the same value, it doesn't contribute to knowing the target value at all.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan for answering! How to specify a variation threshold of a column so I can consider that column? In other words: if I have columns that have the same value for almost all rows except for some rows, when should I delete these columns as well?

Comment: A common way is to measure the correlation of the feature with the target (variants: information gain, conditional entropy). A very low correlation means that the feature doesn't contribute. It's also common to select the top N features based on their correlation with the target (feature selection).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Erwan!